# Prevent calling a getJson if the value is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I have the following Script inside my razor view:-

```
var idRack = $("#Firewall_RackID").val();
        $.getJSON("@Url.Content("~/Firewall/LoadDataCenterANDZoneByRack")", { id: idRack },
        function (RackData) {
            var select = $("#Firewall_TMSRack_DataCenter_Name");
```

which calls the following method:-

```
  public JsonResult LoadDataCenterANDZoneByRack(int id)
        {
            var rack = repository.AllIncludingRack_single(id,a=>a.DataCenter,a=>a.Zone);
            string datacentername = rack.DataCenter.Name;
            string zonename = rack.Zone.Name;

            var Data = new { DCValue = datacentername, ZValue = zonename };

            return Json(Data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

the problem i am facing is that in case the `Firewall_RackID` drop down  is not selected (empty string) , i will get the following error , when i check the scripts using firebug tools:-

> 500 Internal Server Error

so can anyone adivce , how i can prevent the getJSON , from being called incase the var idRack is null or empty ?
Thanks

Comment: Then why don't you check if it's selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `if` statement?

```
var idRack = $("#Firewall_RackID").val();
if (idRack != null || idRack != "") {
    //AJAX
}
```

Comment: @tymeJV i tried this if(idRack) and it worked, not sure if this is different from your approach  ?